# Isolating Excel files which give error in pd.Excelread

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple files (500) from some source. I am trying following code:

```
big_frame = pd.DataFrame()

for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith('.xls'):
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
        #df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
        big_frame = big_frame.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

I am getting following error:

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I want to list out the files which are leading to this error. Can anyone guide me how can I filter out the files which are leading to this error so that dataframe can be built with correct files.

Or is there any change I can make in my code to handle this error.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `try` / `except`.

Comment: Surround your excel file reading with `try except` and in the `except` clause you can print (or do anything with) the name of the file that this error happened with